# Grouping cases with at least three variables in common in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have want to group my dataset by multiple variables and than id those groups. I can id groups when I only group by one variable using dplyr with group_indices.
But I want to group cases by having the same value on at least one of a certain set of variables and then identify the group cases belong to. How to do this in R?

I have the following dataset

```
    NPI name adress phone   
    1    1    1      1          
    2    1    1      1
    3    2    2      2
    4    2    3      3
    5    3    4      4
    6    3    4      5
    7    4    5      6
    8    5    6      6
    9    6    7      7
    10   7    8      8
    11   1    9      9
```

I want cases to be grouped when they have at least one variable of the three I listed (name, adress, phonenumber) in common. 
Cases with most in common to each other should be grouped over cases that have the least in common.
So I want to create a grouping variable which gives cases the same value if they're in the same group. 
You can assume the hierarchy of name>address>phone

```
    NPI name adress phone  org  
    1    1    1      1      1       
    2    1    1      1      1
    3    2    2      2      2
    4    2    3      3      2
    5    3    4      4      3
    6    3    4      5      3
    7    4    5      6      4
    8    5    6      6      4 
    9    6    7      7      5
    10   7    8      8      6
    11   1    9      9      1
```

In the my real dataset I don't have numbers but names, actual addresses and phone numbers. So all the variables I'm working with are string variables.

Comment: why is the last value 1

Comment: Because it shares the name with the first two cases

Comment: Can we assume a hierarchy (which looks implied). As in: Name > Address > Org ?

Comment: yes! although org is not part of the three variables by which the cases should be grouped, org itself is the grouping variable so Name>Address>phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(name, adress, phone) %>%
  mutate(group = c(1, ifelse((name != lag(name)) & (adress != lag(adress)) & (phone != lag(phone)), 1, 0)[-1]),
         group = cumsum(group)) %>%
  arrange(NPI)
```

**Result:**

```
   NPI name adress phone group
1    1    1      1     1     1
2    2    1      1     1     1
3    3    2      2     2     2
4    4    2      3     3     2
5    5    3      4     4     3
6    6    3      4     5     3
7    7    4      5     6     4
8    8    5      6     6     4
9    9    6      7     7     5
10  10    7      8     8     6
11  11    1      9     9     1
```

**Note:**

This works even if `name`, `adress`, and `phone` are all characters. As long as and id column (`NPI`) is numeric, the final data.frame would be in the correct order.

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "   NPI name adress phone   
                1    1    1      1          
                2    1    1      1
                3    2    2      2
                4    2    3      3
                5    3    4      4
                6    3    4      5
                7    4    5      6
                8    5    6      6
                9    6    7      7
                10   7    8      8
                11   1    9      9 ", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate_at(vars(-NPI), as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you useR for helping me, but what I didn't mention is that I'm working with string variables and because of this I can't arrange them so this method doesn't seem to work when I apply it to my actual dataset.

Comment: @BoazKaarsemaker You _can_ arrange string variables, it's just that the ordering would be different than when you're ordering numeric variables. So my solution would work as long as your id column (`NPI`) is numeric. Even if it isn't, the only thing that will be messed up is the ordering of the final rows. The `group` variable would still be created correctly. See my updates. Side note, next time if your original columns are character, please don't provide them as numeric.

Comment: When I'm using the code you provided I get the error:
      Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
      incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 2322
I thought this might be due to the names of the variables also being strings and tried solving this by using s_dplyr a code somebody made to use strings but I couldn't solve it.